# How to detect if a recordset has a next element

Tags: vbscript

I need to test if a recordset has a next element before actually moving to it    with

```
  Recordset.MoveNext
```

EDIT:

I have some records, which are separated with an image but when it comes to the last record there is no need for the image that why I need to test if the record has a next one or it is the last one

```
<% while not Recordset.EOF

 ItemId = Recordset.fields("ITEM_ID")
 itemView= ItemId &" "& Recordset.fields("SHORT_DESC")

%>
<tr> 
<td style="width:240px !important; word-break: break-all;">
<a  href="view_work_item.asp?item_id=<%=ItemId%>&hometoURL=<% =Server.URLEncode(navpath & "/de/ticket/liste_ticket_pl.asp")%>" > 
<%=titemView%></a></td>
<td  background="../../images/white-dot.gif" ><img src="../../images/white-dot.gif" width="1" height="8" ></td>
<td  style="width:240px !important; word-break: break-all;"><%=i%></td>
</tr> 
 //test here if it's the last element don't show this image
<tr> 
<td align="center" class="subnav" colspan="3" height="1"><img src="../../images/white-dot.gif" width="100%" height="1"/></td>
</tr>

<% Recordset.MoveNext   
wend %>
```

Comment: assuming your using DAO  there is a RecordCount property that you can use

Comment: @Sorceri a RecordCount gives the number of records in the record set how this could help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move your `Recordset.MoveNext` statement before your HTML and test it there. You've already saved the recordset values you need so advancing it early won't change anything. And I would think this would work better if you only have a single record, too, since it won't display the image delimiter.

```
If Not Recordset.EOF Then
    Do While True

        ItemId = Recordset.fields("ITEM_ID")
        itemView= ItemId &" "& Recordset.fields("SHORT_DESC")

        Recordset.MoveNext
        If Recordset.EOF Then Exit Do

        ' HTML code here

    Loop
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Recordset.EOF or BOF for begining

```
 if not Recordset.EOF then 
  Recordset.MoveNext
 end
```

To solve you problem try this.

```
<% while not Recordset.EOF

 ItemId = Recordset.fields("ITEM_ID")
 itemView= ItemId &" "& Recordset.fields("SHORT_DESC")
  Recordset.MoveNext
%>
<tr> 
<td style="width:240px !important; word-break: break-all;">
<a  href="view_work_item.asp?item_id=<%=ItemId%>&hometoURL=<% =Server.URLEncode(navpath & "/de/ticket/liste_ticket_pl.asp")%>" > 
<%=titemView%></a></td>
<td  background="../../images/white-dot.gif" ><img src="../../images/white-dot.gif" width="1" height="8" ></td>
<td  style="width:240px !important; word-break: break-all;"><%=i%></td>
</tr> 
<% if not Recordset.EOF then %>
 //test here if it's the last element don't show this image
<%end%>
<tr> 
<td align="center" class="subnav" colspan="3" height="1"><img src="../../images/white-dot.gif" width="100%" height="1"/></td>
</tr>

<% wend %>
```

Comment: I need to test if there is a nexte element before making the move, your solution is not for my need : assuming that I have one element in my recordset and I'm pointing to that one element, the EOF is only detected when I actually move to the next and that's not what I need

Comment: If  Recordset.EOF  AND Recordset.BOF then you will have one record if not you will have more then one.

Comment: Can you add some more code? Are you talking about columns in the record set?